# Scope Issue (NodeJS - "request" package)

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, npm-request

I'm having an issue with the scope of a variable. I need to be able to access "userLocation" outside of "request". The request package can be found at https://github.com/request/request Here's my code below:

```
var request = require('request');  
var userLocation = "";  
request('http://ipinfo.io', function(error, res, body) {  
    var ipDetails   = JSON.parse(body);  
    userLocation    = ipDetails.loc;  
});  
console.log(userLocation);
```

When I try to output the "userLocation" variable, it prints an empty string instead of the details from the request package.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a scope issue. The nature of NodeJS is asynchronous, meaning that `console.log(userLocation)` will not wait your `request` to be completed before it executes. That's why promises and callback functions exist.

If you want to print `userLocation`, move it inside the callback function like so:

```
var request = require('request');  
var userLocation = "";  
request('http://ipinfo.io', function(error, res, body) {  
    var ipDetails = JSON.parse(body);  
    var userLocation = ipDetails.loc;  
    console.log(userLocation);
});
```

Take a look at this [awesome tutorial](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/) if you wish to learn more.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. What if I need to assign the value from "request" to a variable outside of the request function?

Comment: Would a Promise work for you ?  
  
new Promise((res, rej) => {  
  
    var resolve = function (myReqValue){  
        res(myReqValue);  
    }  
  
    request('http://ipinfo.io', function(error, res, body) {  
        var ipDetails = JSON.parse(body);    
        var userLocation = ipDetails.loc;    
        resolve(userLocation);  
    });  
  
}).then((res) => {  
    console.log("Userlocation: " + res)  
});

Comment: @midnightsyntax thanks! that worked perfectly.